# Magento 2 Stop Caching of a Controller

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, full-page-cache, varnish

I have create a module that have a block file, a controller and a template to show
"WHAT OTHER CUSTOMERS ARE LOOKING AT RIGHT NOW" on home page

The controller render the template and show the output (controller called via ajax)

The issue is the content of the template update every time a new product is viewed,So I don't want the output to be cached, how can I stop caching of controller output

Currently I am using Magento's Full page cache and I will be using Varnish On Production

## Updated

### Block

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\Suggestion;

class RightNowCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $_categoryHelper;
     protected $categoryFlatConfig;
     protected $_registry;
     protected $_categoryFactory;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState
    ) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->_registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
        $this->_categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
        
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryFlatConfig = $categoryFlatState;
        
        parent::__construct($context);
        
        $this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => false));
    }

    public function getSomeThing()
    {        
        return 'Something';
    }

}
```

### Controller

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Catalog\Controller\Catalog;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class RightNow extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_listProduct;
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        ListProduct $listProd,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_listProduct = $listProd;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(' heading '));
 
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Catalog\Block\Product\Suggestion\RightNowCollection')
                ->setTemplate('Vendor_Catalog::one.phtml')
                ->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
    }
}
```

Comment: set block  cachable  as false.

Comment: I tried `$this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => null));` in Block class but it did not worked.

Comment: Try like that  'cache_lifetime' => false

Comment: it is not working

Comment: can you provide you block code . i will check it

Comment: i have updated question

Comment: Did you get this work?

Comment: You should set `cacheble="false"` in the layout xml for this handle.
`<bock class="something" name="something" template="something" cacheble="false" />`